# Rails csv row from parent record with many child associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a members table from which I pull :member_id, :client_uid, :first_name, and :last_name.
The Members table has a has_many association to Quality Measures from which I pull :measure and :measure_status for each association and flatten it.

I am trying to get the desired Members data and the flattened Quality Measure data into one CSV row.

Since there can be any number of Quality Measure associated records, I get the max number of associated records and create that number of Measure and Measure Status columns and create the proper number of headers:

```
max_qm_associations = get_max_qm_associations(filtered_members_ids)

    column_headers = ["Member ID", "Client UID","First Name", "Last Name"]

    max_qm_associations.times do |qm|
      column_headers += ["Measure", "Measure Status"]
    end
```

so that the desired output appears like the following assuming the max number of Quality Measure associated records for my Members is 2. Therefore:

| Member ID | Client UID | First Name | Last Name | Measure | Measure Status | Measure | Measure Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23232 | John | Doe | Drink Coffee | Met | Eat | Not Met |
| 2 | 32323 | Jane | Doe | Walk | Met | none | none |

So far I've tried many things. My most recent looks nice enough (but not the goal) by putting the Measure - Measure Status in the first Measure column:

```
csv = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      # Add headers
      csv << column_headers

      filtered_members.each do |member|
        # Add member data
        qm_measures = ""
        member.quality_measures.each do |qm|
          qm_measures << [qm.measure, qm.measure_status.upcase].join(' - ') + "\n"
        end

        csv << [member.id, member.client_uid, member.first_name.humanize, member.last_name.humanize, qm_measures]

      end
    end
```

The result:

| Member ID | Client UID | First Name | Last Name | Measure | Measure Status | Measure | Measure Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23232 | John | Doe | Drink Coffee - Met \n Eat - Not Met |  |  |  |
| 2 | 32323 | Jane | Doe | Walk - Met \n |  |  |  |

Another attempt simply did the above but only as comma separated array values:

```
csv = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      # Add headers
      csv << column_headers

      filtered_members.each do |member|
        # Add member data
        csv << [member.id, member.client_uid, member.first_name.humanize, member.last_name.humanize, member.quality_measures.map {|qm| "#{qm.measure}, #{qm.measure_status}"}.flatten]

      end
    end
```

This result:

| Member ID | Client UID | First Name | Last Name | Measure | Measure Status | Measure | Measure Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23232 | John | Doe | "Drink Coffee,Met", "Eat,Not Met" |  |  |  |
| 2 | 32323 | Jane | Doe | "Walk,Met" |  |  |  |

Again, as a refresher, my desired output is as follows:

| Member ID | Client UID | First Name | Last Name | Measure | Measure Status | Measure | Measure Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23232 | John | Doe | Drink Coffee | Met | Eat | Not Met |
| 2 | 32323 | Jane | Doe | Walk | Met | none | none |

Edits: Table formats keep breaking on submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from this part `member.quality_measures.map {|qm| "#{qm.measure}, #{qm.measure_status}"}.flatten`
it returns you the following array `["Drink Coffee,Met", "Eat,Not Met"]`
You would probably want to do this in your code:

```
member.quality_measures.map{|qm| "#{qm.measure}", "#{qm.measure_status}"}.flatten
```

that will return the ["Drink Coffee","Met", "Eat","Not Met"]
and then you would possibly want to flatten the whole array that you append like so:

```
csv << [member.id, member.client_uid, member.first_name.humanize, member.last_name.humanize, member.quality_measures.map {|qm| "#{qm.measure}", "#{qm.measure_status}"}.flatten].flatten
```

I did not test it yet but it should work if you go in that direction.

Comment: That was it! I was one .flatten away from success. Thanks!

Comment: @Pis7ftw, Your code is really good in my opinion. Just missed this one. If you have the opportunity to test what is the outcome of the line of code in question with binding.pry, byebug or other debugger along the lines I would recommend just calling `object.inspect` or checking what the object looks like in debugger. It helps a big deal to me every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @iseitz!

I was only one .flatten away from my desired output.

```
csv = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      # Add headers
      csv << column_headers

      filtered_members.each do |member|
        qms = member.quality_measures.map {|qm| ["#{qm.measure}", "#{qm.measure_status}"]}.flatten
        csv << [member.id, member.client_uid, member.first_name.humanize, member.last_name.humanize, qms].flatten
      end
    end
```